# How to update angular state's resolve property?

Tags: angularjs

This is my code:

```
.state('app', {
url: '/app',
abstract: true,
controller: 'IndexCtrl as index',
templateUrl: 'index.html',
resolve:{
    loginUser: function (Users) {
        return Users.getLoginUser()
    }
 }
})
```

I want to update this state's resolve loginUser when user choose to logout and login again , is this possible ? If not , is there a way to totally reload angular ? Thank you in advance .

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to reload the state with `$state.reload()`

Just make sure to put the `$state.reload()` into the promise so it doesn't get called too soon.

EDIT:

When the user clicks logout:

```
$scope.logout = function() {
    // Auth service with callback
    Auth.logout(function() {
        // successful logout
        $state.reload();
    }, function(err) {/* handle error */});
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of logout function ? thanks.

Comment: Edited an example using a service with callbacks. How you handle it depends on how you handle your log in/out.